# How can I place a view after html content

Tags: html, css, react-native, webview

My little piece of code is like this.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <WebView
    style={{flex:1}}
    source={{html: content}}
  />
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Text>SOME TEXT</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

I want to show SOME TEXT at the end of all HTML content.

My HTML content is not several lines. This is a minimum of 500 lines. So that it must be scroll. At the end of the scroll, SOME TEXT should come.

Summary: 
I want to show related posts at the end of html content

Comment: Can't you add it injecting it in your `content`? something like `{html: content+"</br><p>SOME TEXT</p>"}`

Answer (score 0):

You should not put Flex:1 in child Views it might take whole space of the screen when you define Flex:1. So I guess you should get your device height first using this..

```
var {_height, _width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

you can set this _height to your WebView and define some height to your `<Text>` and remove that height from the _height you mentioned into the WebView. Something like this..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StatusBar, Image, WebView, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

var {_height, _width} = Dimensions.get('window');

class Example extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style{{flex: 1}}>
                <WebView
                    style={{width: '100%', height: _height - 20}}
                    source={{html: content}}
                />
                <Text style={{width: '100%', height: 20}}>
                    SOME TEXT</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working as wanted me. this is looks like banner ad bar. I want to show related posts at the end of html content

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1}}>
    <WebView style={{ flex: 1 }/>
    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0}}>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If WebView is not showing, that's the issue with RN WebView, try https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview